# Dagger2 Not Generating Dagger* classes

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

As the title says, Dagger2 is not generating the Dagger* prefixed classes. I looked at some other similar posts here but nothing seems to work.

I cloned this repo [https://github.com/ecgreb/mvpc](https://github.com/antoniolg/androidmvp), Invalidated the cache of Android Studio and restarted it, I deleted `$Project/.gradle` and `$Home/.gradle/caches`, Clean and Rebuild the project and still not working.

This has also happened on some projects that are using Dagger2

Am I missing something?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ecgreb.mvpc"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
  testLogging {
    exceptionFormat "full"
    events "started", "skipped", "passed", "failed"
    showStandardStreams true
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

  compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7"
  annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7"
  provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
  testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'
  testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
  testCompile 'org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1'
}
```

The Application class.

```
package com.example.ecgreb.mvpc;

import android.app.Application;

import com.example.ecgreb.mvpc.controller.LoginActivity;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Component;
public class MvpcApplication extends Application {

  @Singleton @Component(modules = { LoginModule.class }) public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
  }

  private ApplicationComponent component;

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //DaggerApplicationComponent IS NOT BEING GENERATED
    component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().build();
  }

  public ApplicationComponent component() {
    return component;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your ApplicationComponent class

Comment: https://github.com/antoniolg/androidmvp You can see the whole code here. @AJay

Comment: there is no `dagger` code on this repo. its only mvp

Comment: You are correct, that's the wrong link. https://github.com/ecgreb/mvpc

Comment: you can use `DaggerApplicationComponent.create()` directly btw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Then instead of

```
 annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7"
```

do

```
 apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7"
```

---

Android-apt won't work in AS 3.0 though, so you'll need `annotationProcessor` in place of every `apt`.

---

If you use Kotlin, then you must replace `annotationProcessor` with `kapt`, and also add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to your build.gradle file

Comment: That worked. But in the setup guide https://github.com/google/dagger they use the `annotaionProccessor`. Also, the generated class name is `DaggerMvpcApplication_ApplicationComponent` I thought they deprecated that convention, shouldn't it be  `DaggerApplicationComponent`?

Comment: This class name happened because your interface is an "inner class" (`public static interface`)

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: The README assumes an updated version of gradle that no longer needs the plugin.  See http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Whats-next-for-android-apt/

Comment: nit: nested class, not inner.  a class defined within another is nested, but inner denotes non-static classes with the implicit parent pointer. i.e. `static` makes only merely nested, not inner

Comment: @gk5885 ah, so that's the term. Sorry I tend to call them `static inner classes` whenever I see one, but I guess it's `nested` :)

Comment: He needed `apt` because he applied `android-apt` plugin

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this kind of issues when using Jack Compiler with your project, you might have seen that none of the solutions work, and the reason is linked to Dagger2 itself. The latest versions don't work well with Jack, I manager to make it work up until the 2.2 version of Dagger2.

Comment: I resolved it by sticking to the old version 2.2 of Dagger2 in my Gradle dependency. If you want to use Jack as a compiler with Dagger you have no other choice as for now.

Comment: I'm using 2.2 with Jack compiler on Java 8, and it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Jack compiler is deprecated, use Retrolambda, or AS 3.0 desugar (part of Android Build Tools), in fact it was already deprecated when you posted this answer, see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html?m=1